# How to display a specific value in a calculated value list field based on a specific string contained in another text field?

Tags: rsa-archer-grc

In a record, a specific string is entered by the user in a text field.

Based on this string and if it matches an existing specific equivalent value, I'd like to display this specific value in a calculated value list field.
e.g. after calculation, this field has to display the value which exactly matches the entered string.

For exemple, if the user exactly enters "1", the value list field must display its "1" value if it exists.
For exemple, if the user exactly enters "abc", the value list field must display its "abc" value if it exists.
If the entered string does not match any known value stored in the value list field, no value is displayed.

This issue is solvable by stacking as many "IF" condition as there are values to match... but this approach is not "clean" and RSA Archer has a technical limitation of 50 "IF" in a calculated field formula.
Therefore, is there any fonction which could help me to do this more efficiently?

Any guidance appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could either go the custom object route and call the REST API to pull back all the values list values if there isn't a ton of values to begin with.  Then compare the text entered by the user to the values list values and set the value that way.

The other is an Archer-to-Archer data feed and set the value that way but don't allow the data feed to create new values.

The custom object approach is real-time whereas the data feed will have a delay before the record is updated.